# Value being exported instead of variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to test out a module that simply exports a number, and a function that increments that number:

```
// counter.js
export var number = 0;
export function increment() {
  number++;
}
```

I'm then using this module as follows:

```
// index.js
import { number, increment } from './counter';

console.log(number);
increment();
console.log(number);
```

I'm using JSPM for the module loading, in case that's important. If I run this I get my expected output:

```
0
1
```

However, if I simply change counter.js to counter.ts and have TypeScript transpile this module, my output ends up being:

```
0
0
```

The transpiled counter.js looks like:

```
// counter.js
"use strict";
exports.number = 0;
function increment() {
    exports.number++;
}
exports.increment = increment;
```

Also, here is my tsconfig.json:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in how TypeScript is transpiling this module (and exporting a constant value for number, rather than the variable itself) or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my tsconfig.json with the following gave me my expected output:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same transpiled output and tsconfig.json settings, but I get the expected output:

```
0
1
```

The only difference I'm seeing is that you're using JSPM here, whereas I am not; I'm just running your code with Node.JS (v6.2.0, with TypeScript 3.8.9).

If it helps, the tsconfig.json documentation for valid [--module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) options says `amd, commonjs, system` are some valid options.

I created a git repo of the working code.

https://github.com/TWebster/counter

I'm debugging with [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) in case it matters.

Comment: Hmm. I just tried running this in Node (transpiling index.js as well) but I got the same results. Any chance you could upload your complete project with this test so that I could try it locally?

Comment: @ChristopherOldfield https://github.com/TWebster/counter - note - index.js is renamed to app.js

Comment: Thanks so much for uploading that. I tested that in Node and it did work for me. I'm guessing that it didn't work in my earlier test because I didn't have the type definitions for Node included in my project.

In good news though, I found that changing module from commonjs to system in tsconfig.json fixed this issue! I'm not sure why it was preventing it from working earlier, but at least I have my fix now. Thanks again for your help!